# Sanic how to locate to static file

Tags: python, jinja2, sanic

I want to locate to static file, because there are many relative path in the html, like:

```
<a href="1.html"> page1 </a>
<a href="2.html"> page2 </a>
....
```

I can use `app.send_static_file()` in ***flask*** to made it.

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",debug=True,port=8888)
```

But for ***Sanic*** I didn't find the relevant method.

```py
from sanic import Sanic
app = Sanic(__name__)
app.static('/static', './static')
@app.route('/')
async def index(request):
    #return "static/index.html" file with static state.
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8888,debug=True, auto_reload=True)
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Or sanic-jinja2, sanic-mako etc. method is fine, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little unclear to me *exactly* what you are looking to do, so I will provide a couple of examples that might be what you are looking for. Please let me know if this does or does not solve the problem and I can amend the answer.

---

### Static files

If you have a single static file (this also works for a directory of static files) that you would like to serve, then you use [`app.static`](https://sanic.dev/en/guide/basics/routing.html#static-files)

```py
app.static("/static", "/path/to/directory")
# So, now a file like `/path/to/directory/foo.jpg`
# is available at http://example.com/static/foo.jpg
```

This would also apply to deeply nested files in `/path/to/directory`.

You can also choose to use this pattern on a single file, often helpful with `index.html` for example:

```
app.static("/", "/path/to/index.html")
```

### Retrieving (or looking up) a URL for a static file

If by "locating" a file you mean you want to get access to its URL, then you would use `app.url_for`

```py
app.static(
    "/user/uploads",
    "/path/to/uploads",
    name="uploads",
)
app.url_for(
    "static",  # Note, for any file registered with app.static, this value is "static"
    name="uploads",
    filename="image.png",
)
```

### Serving files from a route handler

If on the other hand you have a regular route handler and would like to respond with a file (meaning you are doing something more than just serving a static file), then you can use [`sanic.response.file`](https://sanic.dev/en/guide/basics/response.html#file).

Let's imagine a scenario where you need to lookup a user and fetch their profile image:

```py
@app.get("/current-user/avatar")
async def serve_user_avatar(request: Request):
    user = await fetch_user_from_request(request)
    return await file(user.avatar)
```

### Templating

Since you brought up jinja and mako, [Sanic Extensions](https://sanic.dev/en/plugins/sanic-ext/getting-started.html) is an officially supported plugin that adds templating:

```
pip install "sanic[ext]"
```

```py
@app.get("/")
@app.ext.template("foo.html")
async def handler(request: Request):
    return {"seq": ["one", "two"]}
```

[See this PR for alternative methods of serving templates with a `render` function](https://github.com/sanic-org/sanic-ext/pull/39)

### Looking back to your example...

Your example shows this:

```py
app.static('/static', './static')

@app.route('/')
async def index(request):
    #return "static/index.html" file with static state.
```

To me, it looks like you have a file in `./static/index.html` that you want to serve just that file. In this case, the `@app.route` definition is unnecessary, since it will be server because of your `app.static` definition. If you have a folder structure like this:

```
./root
├── static
│   └── index.html
└── server.py
```

Then all you need is:

```py
app.static("/static", "./static")
```

And now you will have: http://example.com/static/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer,I've known what `app.static()` method mean exactly and the url path to make it take effect. And seems that only 'app.static( url, folder)' fit to my situation *( If I return a file instead, relative addresses in html pages will throw a 404 error and I can not jump to the html file with the relative path)*. I will adopt this reply as an correct answer later.